# How to wait for execution control to return from dropping a table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have the following code:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DROP TABLE [" & DatabaseName & "].[" & TableName & "];"
```

Which will drop a table from an MS Access database. Typically this is being done using a database on a shared network.

How can I ensure the `DROP` method completes before allowing the control to move on to the next line in my code?

This is being done in VBA MS Access 2003; but I would be interested if the version impacts the answer.

Comment: Uh, what makes you think it executes asynchronously? I'm pretty sure that the line of code CurrentDB.Execute will not move to the next line until it's complete. Have you encountered a situation where the table still exists in CurrentDB.TableDefs in the following line of code?

Comment: Thats a good point. Actually, I think you are right. in this situation I was checking to see if the table name still existed, but in a 'New' copy of the database object instantiated prior to the CurrentDb.Execute command was executed.

Comment: One gotcha is if you checked to see if the table still existed using DBEngine(0)(0). In that case, the call to return the database object does not refresh the collections, so after the deletion, the table would still show up in the list, unless you refreshed the TableDefs collection before checking it. CurrentDB refreshes all the collections each time it is called, which is the main reason it is so much slower than DBEngine(0)(0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take on the Loop method:

```
Public Function DeleteTable(DatabaseName as String, TableName as String) as Boolean
     DeleteTable = False

        CurrentDb.Execute "DROP TABLE [" & DatabaseName & "].[" & TableName & "];"
        Do
        Loop Until TableExists(TableName, DatabaseName) = False     

     DeleteTable = True
End Function

Public Function TableExists(TableName As String, DatabaseName As String) As Boolean   

        If 0 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(*) As Count FROM [" &   DatabaseName & "].[MSysObjects] WHERE [Name] = '" & TableName & "';").Fields("Count").Value Then
             TableExists = False
        Else
             TableExists = True
        End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a loop with your CurrentDb.Execute command inside.
Inside the loop, you store in a variable the number of tables called TableName.
Until this number = 1, you can't exit from the loop.
When the number becomes at last zero, you can exit from the loop and continue execution.